# Cannot convert object to str implicitly python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python. I have the following code that has a class with three methods problem is at `winCMD = 'NET USE '+ host + ' /User:' + self.user + ' ' + self.password` line it always complains for `self.user` and `self.password` as cannot convert object to int. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import subprocess
#from shutil import copyfile
import shutil
import os

class user_credentials:
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self.user=user
        self.password=password

    def remoteCopyFile(host, self, source, destination):

        winCMD = 'NET USE '+ host + ' /User:' + self.user + ' ' + self.password
        subprocess.call(winCMD, shell=True)
        getFileName=os.path.basename(source)
        tempDestination=r"{0}\{1}".format(destination, getFileName)
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(tempDestination):
                shutil.copy(source, destination)
                print("Copied the Installer File Successfully")
            else:
                print("File alreade exists. Delete and recreate")
        except:
            e=sys.exc_info()[0]
            print("Something went wrong: %s "%e)


    def remoteCopyFolder(host, self, source, destination):

        winCMD = 'NET USE '+ host + ' /User:' + self.user + ' ' + self.password
        subprocess.call(winCMD, shell=True)
        getDirectoryName=os.path.basename(source)
        newDestination=r"{0}\{1}".format(destination, getDirectoryName)

        try:
            if not os.path.exists(newDestination):
                print("copying files please wait....")
                shutil.copytree(source, newDestination)
                print("Copied the entire directory successfully")
            else:
                print("That folder already exists. Delete and recreate again")
        except:
            e=sys.exc_info()[0]
            print("Something went wrong: %s "%e)


    def createFolderOnNetwork(host, self, destination, folderName):   
        winCMD = 'NET USE '+ host + ' /User:' + self.user + ' ' + self.password
        subprocess.call(winCMD, shell=True)
        newPath=r"{0}\{1}".format(destination, folderName)
        if not os.path.exists(newPath):
            os.makedirs(newPath)
            print("Created a folder successfully with name "+folderName)
        else:
            print("The folder already exists. Delete it and recreate")


oUser = user_credentials(r'Admin',r'ThePassword')   
host = "10.90.100.193"  
oUser.remoteCopyFile(host,r"\\vm-tfs\Builds\Athena_2.0\Athena_2.0_20160715.6\AltusDataAccessors.dll",r"\\10.90.100.193\Altus_Latest_Build\Binaries\BuildGen_Test")
oUser.remoteCopyFolder(host,r"\\vm-tfs\Builds\Athena_2.0\Athena_2.0_20160715.6",r"\\10.90.100.193\Altus_Latest_Build\Binaries\BuildGen_Test")
oUser.createFolderOnNetwork(host,r"\\10.90.100.193\Altus_Latest_Build\Binaries\BuildGen_Test","Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **all** your functions you're not actually declaring `self` *as the first parameter* and as a result *`host` get's assigned to the object instance.* When you try to add that to another string with `".. + host + .." you'll get the error you're receiving.

Change all your function declarations to use `self` *as the first parameter* and the issue should leave:

```
def remoteCopyFile(host, self, source, destination):
```

to:

```
def remoteCopyFile(self, host, source, destination):
```